# Angular: Passing selected item to other selectbox

Tags: html, angularjs, mean

I'm building a website on MEAN and I have 2 pages where I want a selected value from one page to use in the other page. Both pages have the same select-box but I want it to change when clicking a `<a href>` item

This is the first page where you can select a cityname: This cityname is being used on the whole page

```
<div  ng-controller="DataCtrl" ng-init="city()">
   <div class="title-1">Seach on city</div>
      <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select>

   <div class="title-1">Central heating problems in {{selectedItem.city}}</div>
      <p>If you want to look for plumbers in {{selectedItem.city}}, click <a href="/search-plumber">here</a></p>
</div>
```

This is the second page

```
<div  ng-controller="DataCtrl" ng-init="city()">
   <div class="title-1">Seach on city</div>
     <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select>

   <div class="title-1">Plumbers in {{selectedItem.city}}</div>
     <p>You have selected Plumbers in {{selectedItem.city}}</p>
</div>
```

Now, when the `<a href>` is clicked, I want to pass the selected cityname to a different page to be used there.

This is the controller where I get the data from my DB

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope,$http){

  $scope.city = function(){
  $scope.items = [];

  $http.get('/getdata').then(function(d){
    $scope.items = d.data;
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
  },function(err){
  console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr?

Comment: If you want you can take gelp of angular events. This will help you pass value from one controller to another . To be clear more about events you can check this links. http://www.riaxe.com/blog/understanding-angulars-scope-and-rootscope-event-system-emit-broadcast-and-on/ . Hope it can help you some how.